# Running a programme over a series of input file names

Tags: python, file-io

I have a programme that I need to run over a bunch of different input files.  I have included the snapshot of this code below.  However, for each iteration, I uncomment the input file I want and comment it out again when the next input file has to be run.  Is there anyway to automate this? Like write a script file that will execute the python programme over each input file specified?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sys
import pydicom # Importing DICOM package 
import csv
import os,string
import pandas as pd


from pyctpatientimagenoise import CTPatientImageNoise


#PathDicom = "./Images/AbdPel Low Dose 3.82 mGy - 192.37 mGy cm/1.2.840.113619.2.437.3.3104443552.660.1564558828.49/"

#------------SET of input files <comment out all others except the 1 input file you want to run the prog on>-----------------------

PathDicom = "./Images/DUKEcases/TCGA-DD-A39X/05-08-1994-CT ABDOMEN wow-06316/"

#PathDicom = "./Images/DUKEcases/TCGA-DD-A11C/05-27-1999-Abdomen120LiverBiPhase Adult-61415/"
#PathDicom = "./Images/DUKEcases/TCGA-DD-A11C/10-28-1998-Thorax04ChestBiphaseLiverPanc Adult-45922/"
#PathDicom = "./Images/DUKEcases/TCGA-DD-A39V/03-08-1994-CT ABDOMEN w  PELVIS w-44494/"
#PathDicom = "./Images/DUKEcases/TCGA-DD-A39V/12-29-1993-CT ABDOMEN wow PELVIS w-26981/"
#PathDicom = "./Images/DUKEcases/TCGA-DD-A39Y/09-16-1994-CT CHEST w-40434/"
#PathDicom = "./Images/DUKEcases/TCGA-DD-A39Y/10-06-1994-CT ABDOMEN w  PELVIS w-56041/"
#PathDicom = "./Images/DUKEcases/TCGA-DD-A113/01-02-1999-Abdomen020APRoutineAbdomenPelvis/"


Examname = []
ImageType=[]
```

Comment: Make a list of input files and process them via a `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Runner script:

```
import subprocess

path_dicom = [
"./Images/DUKEcases/TCGA-DD-A11C/05-27-1999-Abdomen120LiverBiPhase Adult-61415/"
"./Images/DUKEcases/TCGA-DD-A113/01-02-1999-Abdomen020APRoutineAbdomenPelvis/"
 ....
]


for file_path in path_dicom:
     process = subprocess.Popen(args=['python', 'process.py', file_path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

     output, error = process.communicate()
     print(process.returncode)
```

File process script:

```
....
from pyctpatientimagenoise import CTPatientImageNoise

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("Usage python process.py [file_path]")
    sys.exit(-1)

PathDicom = sys.argv[1]

Examname = []
ImageType = []
```

Comment: I like this approach...still trying to implement it. However the script is not producing output.  The print(process.returncode) is giving an output of 1 not 0.

Comment: I added a comma at the end of the 1st file name in path_dicom but the script only ran on 1 input file  - "./Images/DUKEcases/TCGA-DD-A113/01-02-1999-Abdomen020APRoutineAbdomenPelvis/" - which was the 2nd one in the list of input files.  So it didn't do the 1st one.

Comment: Sorry about the comma, add a new tab on lines: "output, error = process.." and "print(process.returncode)" to be inside the for

Comment: AWESOME!!!! it worked. Thanks a ton. I usually learn by doing not simply by reading up different things...so thanks for actually writing code as an example as I am new to Python. I love this elegant code.

Answer (score 0):

```
filepaths = ['foo.bar','foo.baz','foo.bmp']
for filepath in filepaths:
    do_thing()
```

I recommend reading a little more about the basics of Python. It'll save you time in the long run.